# Estimating Quasi-stationary part of a signal

Tags: matlab, statistics, probability, information-theory

I am trying to estimate the Estimating Quasi-stationary part of a signal in Matlab. It is a 1 second long sound signal that belongs to a bird.

I am using MFCC to extract features but would like to have a window size for MFCC that is guaranteed to operate on statistically quasi-stationary part.

My questions are:

1. Do you think it is a solid approach if I iterate by varying my window size from 1 second to a smaller interval by observing the change of second moment of features and making a decision where the second moment is not changing anymore?
2. If I use Shannon entropy method by again varying my MFCC window size, how the number of bits I got at the output of the entropy algorithm would help me to identify the Estimating Quasi-stationary part of the signal

Are there any other ideas?

Comment: Thank you so much for the edit Matt, i apologize for mistakes:)I appreciate it

Comment: You're welcome, no need to apologize. By the way: Welcome to SO!